# Nested LinearLayouts don't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a root vertical `LinearLayout` which contains few `TextView`s and others `LinearLayout` with default orientation (horizontal). However, from some reason, none of these nested `LinearLayout`s is displayed - I have a hunch that they are overflowing the screen width but I am sure how it is possible because I have set the parents orientation to `vertical`. Here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/infoHeadline1"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/infoText1"/>
      <!-- Elements are shown only up to infoText1 -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/infoText2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/infoText3"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/infoText4" />
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/infoText5"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to layout the text into something similar to [this](http://alumni.vsb.cz/7716-internet.html) page. The reason for first nester `LinearLayout` is that I need to make text in the middle of the paragraph bold.

So what is the correct way for nesting layouts in Android?

Comment: put your objective in a image...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in any of the nested LinearLayouts.  Only the first.  Perhaps that is causing your nested layouts to act strangely.

*Would have commented if I had enough reputation...*

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**::

- The code `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
  must only be present in the root view Layout
- Instead you have multiple times defined in your code

---

**Change your code to as below**::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="infoHeadline1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="infoText1" />
        <!-- Elements are shown only up to infoText1 -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="infoText2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="infoText3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="infoText4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="infoText5"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Snapshot**:

[image]

Comment: Can you please try it with longer text?I am still only able to see the first sentence which spans two rows (infoText1)